# BASH: looping through ls

Tags: bash, ls, quoting, loop-device, for

I'm having trouble with this piece of code:

```
22 for filename in "$( ls "$1" | grep ".*\.flac$" )"; do
23                 file_path="$1${filename}"
24                 ffmpeg -i "${file_path}" -f ffmetadata $HOME/metadata
```

Instead of a metadata file on each iteration, I'm getting this error message:

> Downloads/Ariel Pink's Haunted Graffiti - Worn Copy (2005)/01
>   Trepanated Earth.flac **...** 17 Jagged Carnival Tours.flac: **File name too long**

So it appears that inside the loop the $filename variable is equal the names of all FLAC files lumped together.

Of course, omitting quote marks on line 22 results in whitespace problems.

How do I make this work? I'm new to bash and very confused.

Comment: use `find` instead of your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
 for filepath in "$1/"*.flac 
 do
      ffmpeg -i "${file_path}" -f ...
```

where

- `"$1/"*.flac` will garantee .flac suffix in the end
- be sure to quote `"${file_path}"`
- basename can be found using `bn=$(basename "${file_path}")`
- un flac'ed basename can be found using `bnnf=$(basename "${file_path}" .flac)`

sample

```
A > ls -l Music 
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 foo bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 foo bar.flac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 fubar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 fubar.flac
```

now run:

```
 A > for f in Music/*.flac; do echo $f; ls -l "$f" ; done 
Music/foo bar.flac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 Music/foo bar.flac
Music/fubar.flac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Arc Arc 0 Mar 14 03:37 Music/fubar.flac
```

Comment: I haven't used it in my script yet, but I did some debugging and it seems to work. The solution looks so simple I'm confused even further. :)

Thank you!